# How to fix lighting in a scene?

Tags: lighting

[image]I am having trouble with the lighting in my scene. It seems a bit hazy, the lights don't really do a lot, and I'm looking for the model to look like it does in the viewport shader - which is extremely glossy skin and metallic hair - however this isn't showing up in render mode. Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello please show some screenshots. If you're talking about the Material Preview, keep in mind that it uses HDRIs (360° image), have you plugged an environment texture with HDRI into the Background of your World?

Comment: @moonboots thank you, I have used an HDRI - I have uploaded a screenshot of the issue now, the one on the left is the viewport shader and the one on the right is what happens when I render.

Comment: is the left image Rendered Preview or Material Preview? If it's the case, what's the Viewport Shading setting? Are Scene Lights and Scene World options activated?

Comment: The cropping on the current screenshots omits settings around the workspace needed to troubleshoot the issue.  And it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem (remember to pack the relevant image textures into the blend). The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help